# Under Google Chrome, the blue border line shows

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Q1. Under Google Chrome, when mouse points at the right side mon, the blue border line shows, how to solve this problem also? (other browser does not present any problem)

Q2. I browse under microsoft IE11, far right side ’s contact menu being cut off half, other browser looks normal, how to solve this problem ?

my web: http://vicky.bixone.com/ecoxx/

Comment: Set `outline: none;` to `.navbar-button`.

Comment: Thank very much! You are the best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this is the problem you are facing https://prnt.sc/p6n4k1
it is because of outline, you can add this code to your css for solving the issue

for only this issue

```
.navbar-button.show-info:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

and for 2nd question you need to add cross browser support https://www.screencast.com/t/QRHl1s83H

```
-webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px);

-ms-transform: translate(0px, 0px);
```

Comment: You've been a lifesaver. Thank you very much.  T_T

Answer (score 1):

its `Outline` Apply below css.

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: hyperlinks blue line is disappear, It's amazing!!!
You are so great, thank you verrrrrrrrrrrrrrrry much!